# Aurelia: Configure proxy path for API calls

Tags: cors, fetch, aurelia

I'm building my first Aurelia application, and trying to call my API as follows:

```
const data = await this.httpClient.fetch('https://my-api-server/api/employees').then(response => response.json());
```

This causes the following error in the browser:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://my-api-server/employees. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).
```

This is totally expected. My approach to dealing with CORS with all other JS frameworks that I've worked with so far (Angular, React, Vue.js, Express with vanilla JS) used to be to set up a proxy path in the web server for API calls, as in:

```
If request URL starts with "/api",
then remove "/api", and re-route request to "https://my-api-server"
```

I can't figure out how to configure this in Aurelia. Any pointers? Am I approaching this in the wrong way?

I know that I could add the relevant CORS headers to my API responses, but I don't believe that to be the right approach. This API is used by multiple applications and shall not be changed to appease one particular consumer.

Comment: Aurelia runs solely in the browser, it does not have a server. You will need to tell us what server you are using to serve your application.

Comment: @AshleyGrant Thanks! I think you set me on the right path. 
I used the aurelia-cli to create the project, selecting "Web" as the target platform. I can see it uses webpack-dev-server, which I'd prefer not to use, since it is intended for development only. 

I changed it to use express instead. I'm currently trying to get automatic building and browserSync going using https://gist.github.com/zewa666/ca1d5b0cf1fdccd5f756948fa64c66dd as a guide. 

I'll post on this question once I've found a satisfactory solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Ashley Grant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2167109/ashley-grant) pointed out, this doesn't really have anything to do with Aurelia specifically. I guess it's just that the code produced by the Aurelia-CLI, when you select "Default ESNext / Typescript app" (or "custom", then "Web" for the platform) doesn't provide for a quick way to set up a proxy path.

This default starter-code uses webpack-dev-server for serving the app, so I changed this to Express, because:

1. webpack-dev-server is intended for development use only
2. With Express I can easily set up a special route with a handler to make the proxy API call.

The starter code already uses webpack to build the app to a `dist` folder, so I implemented the Express server like so to serve the files in `dist` in a server.js:

```js
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const request = require('request');

app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));
app.get('/', (_req, res) => res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html')));

app.all('/api/*', function(req, res) {
  request('https://my-api-server' + req.url.substring(4), 
    { 
      method: req.method, 
      body: (req.method === 'POST' || req.method === 'PUT') ? JSON.stringify(req.body) : null
    }, 
    function(error, response, body) {
      if (error)
        res.status(500).send({ message: 'Error calling My API service: ' + (error.code ? error.code : error) });
      else
        res.status(response.statusCode).send(body);
    });
});

app.listen(9000);
```

Running it is then a simple matter of executing `node server.js`

I actually took it farther and created a [gulpfile.js](https://github.com/bhaeussermann/aurelia-northwind/blob/main/gulpfile.js) with tasks to build and run the server, as well as rebuild and reload in response to source file changes using browserSync, using `gulp-live-server` to run Express via server.js